# Glide - Cannot resolve method override

Tags: android, android-glide

i am having trouble with Glide from  past 2 days. It was working fine but when the update came for Glide depandency it gives me error in my previous code.

**here is my code:**

```
  private void showImage(Uri uri, int dimenInPx) {
    Glide.with(context)
            .load(uri)
            .override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx)
            .transform(new CircleTransform(context))
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_display_pic)
            .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_displayPic));
}
```

.override, .transform and .placeholder is not identifying by Glide.

**My Gradle file:**

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
```

Yes i know this is old version, but i even tried with latest version which is...

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
```

I don't know where i am doing wrong. Please help me out. Thanks

**Update 1:**
I update Glide to latest depandency and  then modified my code which is provided by @Ratilal and it looks like this now:

```
Glide.with(context)
 .load(uri)
 .apply(new RequestOptions()
 .override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx)
 .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_display_pic)
 .transform(new CircleTransform(context)))
 .into((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_displayPic));
```

So now the error is gone, but i get run time NoSuchMethodError.

```
No virtual method load(Landroid/net/Uri;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager' appears in /data/app/com.scoratech.scoraxchange-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
```

Comment: Post the full gradle file..

Comment: In my case it is working with compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: @RatilalChopda, yes checking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **4.3.1** you can use like this.

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(YOUR_URL)
     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx).placeholder(R.drawable.placeHolder).error(R.drawable.error_image))
     .into(imageview);
```

Comment: @KhanStan99 what is the issue in this answer.

Comment: Okay, this is not giving any error, but i am having trouble with OnClick button event. let me resolve that. ill update here once its done.

Comment: So here is the update,  when i click image pick button it throws this error:
  
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method load(Landroid/net/Uri;)Lcom/bumptech/glide/DrawableTypeRequest; in class Lcom/bumptech/glide/RequestManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.bumptech.glide.RequestManager' appears in /data/app/com.scoratech.scoraxchange-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)

Answer (score 2):

Use latest version with [**`RequestOptions`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions) .

```
RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
    .fitCenter()
    .override(dimenInPx, dimenInPx);

Glide.with(context)
    .load("URL")
    .apply(myOptions)
    .into(ImageView);
```

Kindly follow [**`Migrating from v3 to v4`**](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions) .

Comment: yes, tried this. no success.

Comment: @KhanStan99 I have edited answer.

Comment: @RatilalChopda's answer gave me no errors, but i got another small issue.
once check his answer

Comment: @KhanStan99 Solve the problem ?

Comment: yes ratilal answer worked. even you way of doing it also same.